# Visual Studio 17 - example colors visibility

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, colors

When I'm typing code in XAML for example: 
`<Listview BackgroundColor="Black"/>`
I've seen that some coders got boxes near color name. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to get a Visual Studio extension (from the Tools menu) that is a color picker.  A couple of choices, in no order:

- Color Picker
- Inline Color Picker
- VS Color Picker

Comment: Thank You mate, You helped a lot !